# jquery mobile calendar opens other calendar when date is set

Tags: jquery-mobile

i have 3 datebox fields one under another. When i open first calendar, its SET DATE button comes over the 3rd field. So when i tap on the SET DATE it also gets click on the 3rd field and its calendar opens up...

Right now i am doing this, but its not a good idea and also doesn't works in all browsers

```
if(passed.method === 'close'){ // If first field calendar close
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(3rd field calendar).datebox('enable');
        $(3rd field calendar).blur();
        $(3rd field calendar).datebox('close');
    }, 500);
}
```

Kindly suggest

Comment: Which calendar implementation are you using?

Comment: <input type="text" class="txtbox" value="" name="date" id="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox"}' >